# Getting score from a list of matches

Tags: python, list

I want to write a script that from a list like that

```
Matches=[ ("Team Name1", 120, "Team Name2", 56 ), ... ,]
```

which is a list of matches, with two team names who played and their results, give me as output a list with each Team Name and its score (2 points for each win). My output should look like that:

```
Team             Score
Team Name 1      26
Team Name 2      30
...
```

I've reached something like that

```
for match in matches:
    score=0
    if match[1] > match[3]:
        score + = 2
        res=[match[0],score]
```

There's also the thing that each Team do NOT play just once in the Matches list.

Comment: What is the input, what is the output? it's not clear from your question.

Comment: The Matches list is my input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help.

```
matches=[ ("A", 120, "B", 56 ), ("A", 120, "C", 56 ), ("B", 120, "C", 56 )]

TEAM={}

for match in matches:
    TEAM[match[0]]=0
    TEAM[match[2]]=0

for match in matches:
    if match[1] > match[3]:
        TEAM[match[0]]+=2
    elif match[3] > match[1]:
        TEAM[match[2]]+=2



for match in TEAM:
    print match, ":", TEAM[match]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not proposing this as an answer, it is just a suggestion that the accepted answer can also be written this way:

```
matches=[ ("A", 120, "B", 56 ), ("A", 120, "C", 56 ), ("B", 120, "C", 56 )]

TEAM={}

for match in matches:
    if not match[0] in TEAM:
        TEAM[match[0]] = 0
    if not match[2] in TEAM:
        TEAM[match[2]] = 0
    if match[1] > match[3]:
        TEAM[match[0]] += 2
    elif match[3] > match[1]:
        TEAM[match[2]] += 2

for match in TEAM:
    print(match, ":", TEAM[match])
```

This isn't a significant change, just an alternative.